# npm ci is failing intermittently with "error cb() never called!" Node@14.16.1 and npm@6.14.12

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-ci

We have a few build pipelines that are failing intermittently with "error cb() never called!" for npm ci. This error is displayed after it downloaded and extract a random npm package (in case of below log it is date-fns@2.30.0).

We are using "npm ci --loglevel verbose", also before this there is task to run "npm cache verify". The build server has Node@14.16.1 and npm@6.14.12, the same on development environment. We are using a private DevOps Artifacts Feeds for npm packages.

Just for clarification, these build pipelines run successfully sometimes. I tried "npm cache clean --force", also manually cleaned/deleted npm-cache folder of the build server but didn't help.

Anyone encountered with similar situation, please share your experience or input that may help. Thank you in advance.

```
5222 http fetch GET 200 https://tfs /npm/registry/@progress/kendo-inputs-common/-/kendo-inputs-common-3.1.0.tgz 7027ms
5223 silly extract @progress/kendo-inputs-common@3.1.0 extracted to  \node_modules\@progress\kendo-inputs-common (15868ms)
5224 silly extractTree tslib@2.6.2 ->  \node_modules\@progress\kendo-inputs-common\node_modules\tslib
5225 silly tarball trying tslib@2.6.2 by hash: sha512-AEYxH93jGFPn/a2iVAwW87VuUIkR1FVUKB77NwMF7nBTDkDrrT/Hpt/IrCJ0QXhW27jTBDcf5ZY7w6RiqTMw2Q==
5226 silly tarball no local data for tslib@2.6.2. Extracting by manifest.
5227 http fetch GET 200 https://tfs /npm/registry/react-reconciler/-/react-reconciler-0.26.2.tgz 19480ms
5228 http fetch GET 200 https://tfs /npm/registry/tslib 3150ms
5229 silly extract react-reconciler@0.26.2 extracted to  \node_modules\react-reconciler (270928ms)
5230 http fetch GET 200 https://tfs /npm/registry/tslib/-/tslib-2.6.2.tgz 2475ms
5231 silly extract tslib@2.6.2 extracted to  \node_modules\@progress\kendo-inputs-common\node_modules\tslib (6776ms)
5232 http fetch GET 200 https://tfs /npm/registry/@progress/kendo-theme-default/-/kendo-theme-default-5.12.0.tgz 56505ms
5233 silly extract @progress/kendo-theme-default@5.12.0 extracted to  \node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-bootstrap\node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default (70471ms)
5234 http fetch GET 200 https://tfs /npm/registry/date-fns/-/date-fns-2.30.0.tgz 402958ms
5235 silly extract date-fns@2.30.0 extracted to  \node_modules\date-fns (490761ms)
5236 timing npm Completed in 984617ms
5237 error cb() never called!
5238 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
5239 error <https://npm.community>

##[debug]Agent.BuildDirectory= BuildAgent3\_work\405
##[debug]rm -rf  BuildAgent3\_work\405\npm
##[debug]removing directory
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
Finishing: npm clean install - XXX.Web
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cb() never called!" error was due to the mismatch version of the npm packages in package.json and package-lock.json. Mostly, in case where package.json had lower version and package-lock.json had higher version it was throwing error.

To solve the issue, I have to look for such packages and align the version in both package.json and package-lock.json.

Also, the [npm@8.6.0](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5113) validates package and package-lock for such mismatches. It is advisable to use npm@8.6.0 to later.